# Sending an email blast only goes to certain users

Tags: rules, emails, users

A little background on the problem:  I have been tasked with figuring out a problem in a Drupal site that I have no experience with.  I have done Web Development using PHP, etc. but never used Drupal.  I have a parent site with 3 sites underneath, and roles for each user (can be members of all sites or just one).  I have a rule that sends an email out to these users after certain content is submitted.  However, not all of the users receive the emails (about 150-180 users per email blast).

Does anyone have suggestions as to how I can go about debugging and figuring out this problem?  I have to fix this by tomorrow.  Here is what I have done so far:

-Made sure users were assigned to the role in the email rule.
-Unchecked the box "send only to active users"

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: it's likely all of the emails are being sent by the server and go missing in transit. You would be better off sending your emails through a service rather than from your server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Do you have any suggestions on email services to try out?

Comment: http://www.mailgun.com/, https://postmarkapp.com/, http://mandrill.com/ - any email provider that does transactional email wil work. There are a ton. http://www.upaknee.com/ is a good Canadian solution if you're in Canada. You'll need to contact them regarding transactional email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default PHP mailer has a lot of issues, and sometimes mails are not received or accepted by the servers as this a common method for sending spam.

A good practice is to use the SMTP module (https://drupal.org/project/smtp) for sending emails. You need to connect it to a server (eg. google) for authentification and then it replaces the default drupal php mailer.

Comment: This is another option, probably better than using a service.

Comment: Thanks @Neograph734.  I tried to vote up your answer but I don't have enough rep....I will try to do this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I see you marked this question as answers already. So I assume it worked :).